# Confusion regarding matrix representation properties

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, finite-groups, representation-theory, orthonormal

I am studying about matrix representation of finite groups. If the group is defined as
\begin{equation}
G=\{e,a,b,c,.....\}
\end{equation}
then the matrix representation is defined by the collection of non-singular matrices
\begin{equation}
T=\left\{T(e),T(a),T(b),T(c),.....\right\}
\end{equation}
The representation has the property that
\begin{equation}
T(a)T(b)=T(ab) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
I am trying to prove $(3)$ using the fact that if $\{\phi_i\}$ be a set of orthonormal basis vectors of the vector space where the operators of $G$ act, then operation of an element $a\in G$ on a basis vector would be given by:
\begin{equation}
a\phi_i=\sum_j T_{ij}(a) \phi_j \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Using $(2)$, I can write for $a,b \in G$,
\begin{align}
(ab)\phi_i &=a\left(\sum_j T_{ij}(b) \phi_j\right)\\
&=\sum_j T_{ij}(b) a\phi_j\\
&=\sum_{k}\left(\sum_j T_{ij}(b) T_{jk}(a)\right)\phi_k \tag{3}
\end{align}
Also, as $ab \in G$ for $a,b \in G$, we can write
\begin{equation}
(ab)\phi_i=\sum_k T_{ik}(ab)\phi_k \tag{4}
\end{equation}
Comparing $(3)$ and $(4)$, I am getting
\begin{equation}
T_{ik}(ab)=\sum_j T_{ij}(b) T_{jk}(a)
\end{equation}
However, in order to prove $(1)$, I had to show instead that
\begin{equation}
T_{ik}(ab)=\sum_j T_{ij}(a) T_{jk}(b)
\end{equation}
I am not getting where did I go wrong. Can anyone please help me in this derivation?

Comment: How are you getting what you wrote in, let's call it (5), by comparing (3) and (4)? And why are you trying to prove (1)?

Comment: @blargoner I have edited my question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard definition of the matrix $T(a)$ representing the linear action of $a$ relative to a (not necessarily orthonormal) basis $\lbrace\phi_i\rbrace$ is
$$
a\phi_i = \sum_j T_{ji}(a)\phi_j.
$$
Note this differs from your expression (2) in the order of the indices. Using this should give the result you seek.

Comment: Thank you! Now got it. Can you please tell me the reference from where you got this equation?

Comment: Literally any book on linear algebra will explain this. See for example footnote 11 in [the wikipedia entry on linear maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map).